# How to remove border of window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, window

This is default window when create project by WPF template :

```
<Window x:Class="Chaco.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chaco"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        BorderThickness="0"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonMain" Content="Main" Width="100" Height="50" Background="White">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The default window has black border.
[image]

How to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `Window.WindowStyle="ToolWindow"`. You will still have a shadow.

```
<Window x:Class="Chaco.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chaco"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonMain" Content="Main" Width="100" Height="50" Background="White">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or you can set `WindowChrome.WindowChrome` attached property, setting `GlassFrameThickness="0"` will also remove the shadow:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Another way would also be to set `WindowStyle="None"` and `AllowsTransparency="True"` by the window.

Comment: Nice trick! But the downside is that there is still a border at the top when the window is active. Also the Minimize and Maximize buttons are gone

Comment: I don't see any Border, may be indent, but not the border. Yes unfortunately there are no buttons. So they have to be added manually.